# C++ Comparing vector elements to determine correct answer

Tags: c++, vector, string-comparison

I have been fighting with this for awhile. I am trying to create a score results from 2 vectors, 1 vector being the actual answer and the other being the entered answer.
Essentially comparing:

```
for (i=1;i<=totalQ;i++){
cout<<"Enter question answer: ";
cin>>inputQ;
questions.push_back(inputQ);
}
```

to this:

```
for (i=1;i<=totalQ;i++){
    cout<<"Enter your answer: ";
    cin>>studentA;
    answers.push_back(studentA);
    }
```

I cant quite figure out how to compare the elements with each other to return how many are the same (correct answers).

initially i tried without using the second vector, and comparing the string from the second input to the questions vector by doing this:

```
for (i=1;i<=totalQ;i++){
    cout<<"Enter your answer: ";
    cin>>studentA;
       if(studentA == questions[i]){
          score=score+1}
    }
```

but the compare statement kept causing the program to crash. After researching a bit i came to the conclusion that I wouldnt be able to compare the vector using [] so i decided to create a vector to compare the 2... which hasnt panned out.

How can i compare the 2 vectors to provide the amount of matching elements and indexes, or how could i compare an input to a vector element.

Both vectors are string vectors, and studentA was a string variable.

Comment: Your original code was probably crashing because you keep using 1-based indexing, and `questions[i]`, when `i == totalQ`, indexes beyond the `vector`'s bounds. I don't understand what you're asking ... you have *N* questions and *N* answers, and want to match each answer to a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
    int i;
    int score = 0;
    int totalQ = 3;

    vector<string> questions;
    vector<string> answers;

    for (i=0;i<totalQ;i++)
    {
        string inputQ;
        cout<<"Enter question answer: ";
        cin>>inputQ;
        questions.push_back(inputQ);
    }

    for (i=0;i<totalQ;i++)
    {
        string studentA;
        cout<<"Enter your answer: ";
        cin>>studentA;
        answers.push_back(studentA);
    }

    for (i=0;i<totalQ;i++)
    {
        //if(strcmp(answers[i].c_str(), questions[i].c_str()) == 0)
        if(answers[i].compare(questions[i]) == 0)
        {
            score++;
        }
    }

    cout << "You got " << score<< " correct" << endl;
}
```

I've assumed that you store your answers as strings.

The things you need to remember are

1. To start your indexes from 0, this is how they are accessed in the vector using operator []. You wont need the `<=` in your loop and it wont crash as you wont overrun your vector by one.
2. To compare the strings in a loop you can use either the `compare` method of the string or good old fashioned `strcmp`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak a few things, but implementing the compare method did exactly what i was looking for. I had previously tried strcmp but it wouldnt function for string. IIRC from readings it is limited to char applications, no?

Comment: @ErikKessel you can see how to use `strcmp` in the commented out section.

Answer (score 1):

use the std::find function, for example, assuming answers is the vector of correct answer, and *answer* is the entered answer:

```
if( std::find(answers.begin(), answers.end(), answer) != answers.end() ) {
      score+=1;
}
```

by the way, your program crashes because your index starts from 1 and ends with size:

```
for (i=1;i<=totalQ;i++){
```

in C++ vector index starts from 0, so you it should be:

```
for (i=0;i<totalQ;i++){
```

Comment: I didnt think the 1 made much difference, i was using it because totalQ is defined by the user so instead of making it (i=0;i<totalQ-1;i++) i thought the 1 would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is not looping through the whole vector. Indices start at 0, and use < instead <= .in example 2 you forgot a semicolon. Use score++; instead of score = score+1. Accessing a vector of size N at index N causes your program to crash since indices start at 0